# Multiupload Image Using Image List in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm newbie. I try make app for upload some image using flutter. I have successfully pick some image from image picker, but when I try to write data to firebase storage, only one image was successfully uploaded. This is my code :

```
List<File> _imageList = [];
File _image;

  Future uploadFile() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    final userId = user.uid;
    final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(userId).child('images');
    final StorageUploadTask task = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
    return task;
  }
```

And this my code for select and display image

```
 Future getImageFromGallery() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
      _imageList.add(_image);
    });
  }

List<Widget> builtImageDisplay() {
    return [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: new Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: _imageList.length == 0
                ? new Image.asset('assets/images/format.jpg')
                : GridView.count(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    primary: false,
                    crossAxisCount: 4,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                    children: _imageList.map((File file) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: new GridTile(
                          child: new Image.file(
                            file,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ];
  }
```

Comment: for late visitors here is an answer to upload a list of images and get the download URLS https://stackoverflow.com/a/60128263/10409567

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple `function` to Upload Multiple Image Files.

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

  Future<Null> _uploadImages() async {
    _imageList.forEach((f) {
      final StorageReference _ref = storageImageRef.child(basename(f.path));
      final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = _ref.putFile(f);
    });
```

Comment: anmol.mahjhail Got It! Thanks.. U save my day! ^_^

Comment: how can i get all download urls?