# How to write document in firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am a complete noob to Google Cloud functions
I have a couple of files in Cloud Storage, I would like to receive download url of these files and then write them in documents in firestore.

I am using getSignedUrl, it runs but it doesn't do anything. The console shows "Deploy Complete"

```
function getSignedUrl() {
  const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')({
    keyFilename: './modulus-1464f-firebase-adminsdk-yvpt8-09ae0000ad'
  });
  // ...
  const bucket = gcs.bucket('modulus-1464f');
  const file = bucket.file(files);
  console.log('signedUrls');
  return file.getSignedUrl({
    action: 'read',
    expires: '03-09-2491'
  }).then(signedUrls => {
    console.log(signedUrls);
    const url = data[0];
    console.log(url);
    return data[0];


  });
}
```

Comment: You could search for tutorials online. You also might wanna see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53183066/flutter-upload-batch-of-images-and-get-all-those-urls-to-store-in-firestore

Comment: "doesn't do anything" isn't enough information to work with.  Your code should check for errors and do more logging to illustrate what it actually does do.